# Unified Service Desk Single Sign On Option

Tags: unified-service-desk

Unified Service Desk has a tab for CRM Page, which when opens ask for CRM Credentials again.

I couldnt find much on internet other then i found one option which is creating an option record with

name = SingleSignOnEnabledBrowsers

value = chrome

Still its not working and always ask for login.

Any solutions?

Comment: FYI - I have tried the same thing. Cannot get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-service-desk/admin/connect-dynamics-365-instance-using-unified-service-desk-client?view=dynamics-usd-4.1#understand-sso-for-unified-service-desk

USD Client has to be 4.1.x.x and SSO is enabled for Chrome Process. that means hosted control has to be of hostingtype chrome.